# Crontab doesn't run Wget with a url with parameters

Tags: php, aptana, cron

I'm using Aptana Cloud without root access.

WORKS:

`* * * * * /usr/sfw/bin/wget -qO- 'http://myproject.aptanacloud.com/myproject/myphp.php' | /bin/mail mymail@mymail.com`

DOESN'T WORK!:

`* * * * * /usr/sfw/bin/wget -qO- 'http://myproject.aptanacloud.com/myproject/myphp.php?param1=blog%2frss2.xml' | /bin/mail mymail@mymail.com`

I tried either unsuccessfully url with quotes, double quotes or without quotes.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you measure that it works or it does not? What about trying echo instead of wget?

Comment: Using echo doesn't make sense, the problem is how wget is called from crontab. It works because I got mailed with result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just out of curiosity: have you tried doing it without the %2f and using a straight forward slash instead? Maybe it's the encoding there that's breaking something.

Comment: As you predicted url encoding was breaking something inside crontab. Even inside quotes...
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

From:

man 5 crontab

Percent-signs (%)  in  the  command,  unless escaped  with backslash (), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.